# adding a function to a mips program

Tags: mips

I have wrote a function for my mips program in a separate file from the main program that was provided to test with. How do I add the function I built to the main program that was provided? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: You haven't even specified your target environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy create a new code by taking the code you have been given for main and then making a function of the code you in the separate file. Then you can just call the function from the main and run them both at the same time.